# How to enable multiple bulk email address just for organizations?

Tags: civimail, duplicate-contacts, mailing

The question is about the seeting
**Enable multiple bulk email address for a contact.**
in /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing

The problem is that in I have many organizations that have multiple emails. Each of those emails needs to receive mailings, i.e. different official emails within one organization need to be informed about something.

However, while that is true for organizations, I don't want the individuals receiving mailings through all the email address associated with them.

How would I go about doing this?

My thinking was that I could put all the non-primary emails of every individual on hold. But I would like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at editing the email for a contact - you will see a column to the right of the on hold column that says bulk mailings. You only need to tick one box for a contact and that is how it will be when you enable the multiple bulk mailing addresses. Using on hold would not be a good idea as that has another purpose and is set by the system when an address bounces.